# How do you transfer large amounts of content to a new WordPress theme without down time?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming, themes, cost-management

I'm working on a non-profit's website and social media presence. They are currently using an outdated website built on WordPress and we're working on a limited budget to improve it. I have suggested we go with a more up-to-date WordPress theme as this would keep costs as low as possible.

The question that remains is how easy/cost-effective (in terms of labor) is it to take a large amount of content (mostly text) and transfer it to a new WordPress theme? Would this mean the website would be down for an extended period of time while we implement existing content? or would we be able to backup the content, apply a new theme, and upload the content from the backup? Is this a simple process or an extended process? I'm going to estimate there are about 150-200 pages worth of content. At a rate of $30/hour for labor, how much would this end up costing us?

Comment: A theme doesn't affect content.  Moving servers / installations does.  Asking us how much it will cost is nonsense: It would cost around a hundred dollars for me to move a site (at $125 / hour).  It might cost a thousand dollars for a novice at $30 per hour.  It all depends on how long it takes the person doing the work to get it done.  And - BTW - migrating from one install to another is only minimally affected by the number of pages.  The number of static assets (uploaded images, etc) come into play, as they affect download / upload time.

Answer (score 1):

Changing theme does not affect website availability. Before changing the theme permanently, check it in live preview for any incompatibility.
There many backup plug-ins out there. [UpdraftPlus](https://updraftplus.com/) is a good one and you can use it to backup locally/and on [Google drive](https://www.google.com/drive/) for free (other cloud storages are not supported in free version AFAIK).